# Backbone.Router wrong match fragment

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have the following `routes object`:

```
    routes: {
        "*defaults": "home",
        '#test': 'test'
    }
```

Here's the url options:

```
myApp.html // home is called as desired 

myApp.html#test // home is called instead of test
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router), you don't need the hash mark in the route (that's implied by the Backbone routing convention).  Also, the "*defaults" route is going to catch everything, so you should put it last after more specific routes.  So, like this:

```
routes: {
    'test': 'test'
    "*defaults": "home",
}
```

Should result in *myApp.html#test* getting routed to *test*.